prevent sjlabelled from automatically copying labels when creating new variable using mutate
When I create a new variable using variables that have labels, the new variable seems to inherit the label of one of the variables I am supplying. Is this a bug or how can I prevent this? I can obviously give the new variable a new label or remove the old one but I don't want to have to do this for each variable I create
library(sjlabelled)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(aa = c(1),
                 bb = c(2)) %>% 
  var_labels(
    aa = "label a",
    bb = "label b")
df

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(cc = aa + bb)


# I want to avoid having to relabel the variable
# df <- df %>% 
#   var_labels(
#   cc = "")



First of all nice, you use dark mode! This behavior occurs because sjlabelled retains variable labels during data transformations, which is by design rather than a bug. When you create a new variable using mutate, the new variable inherits the label from one of the contributing variables (usually the first). If you don't want the new variable to inherit any label automatically, use this custom mutate_strip_labels instead:
library(sjlabelled)
#install.packages("sjlabelled")
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(aa = c(1),
                 bb = c(2)) %>% 
  var_labels(
    aa = "label a",
    bb = "label b")

# remove label from newly mutated columns
mutate_strip_labels <- function(.data, ...) {
  # Capture the state before mutation
  old_vars <- names(.data)
  
  # Perform the mutation
  new_data <- mutate(.data, ...)
  
  # Capture the state after mutation
  new_vars <- setdiff(names(new_data), old_vars)
        
  # Remove labels from any new variables
  for (var in new_vars) {
    # Directly modify the column's label
    new_data[[var]] <- set_label(new_data[[var]], label = "")
  }
  
  new_data
}

df <- df %>% 
  mutate_strip_labels(cc = aa + bb)

Output:


thanks, thats useful but it seems overly complicated for such a task. I still don't understand why this would be a design feature. By definition, a new variable should be different than a variable already in the dataset, and hence, it should also have a different label indicating this?

My best guess is that they did not put any thought into this. But in any case it would pose the problem what to label the newly created variable with. How should mutate know, how to label the new column?

It shouldn't know! So it should leave it blank I would have thought....
